# How can I solve the issue: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('String data, right truncation: length 162 buffer 160', 'HY000')

Tags: python, sql, buffer, pyodbc

I have an issue with inserting data to my database, probably because my parameters are to long. Is there a way to increase buffer?

The issue:
`pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('String data, right truncation: length 162 buffer 160', 'HY000')`

My code where the issue appears:

```
@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    print("FUNC call")
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True
```

Comment: Check the length of the data elements you are trying to insert or update against the maximum length of the corresponding columns. You appear to be trying to apply an 81-character string to a column of type `nvarchar(80)`.

Answer (score 2):

More likely to be related to type conversion.
I had similar error when I was trying to save string datetime which looks like '2023-07-13T17:55:28.075Z' directly to a datetime column in database.
Converting it first to an actual datetime fixed the problem:

```
datetime.fromisoformat(created_at)
```